# Reload UITableview after back

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have simple table on my View. Another view have array with some values. When I back, I want to reload table with new values, but dont work.

My class:

```
 let textCellIdentifier = "cell"
var menu:[[String]] = [[]]
var buscaEmp:BuscadorEmpresa = BuscadorEmpresa()


@IBOutlet weak var tablaVista: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    recuperaEmpresas()
    tablaVista.delegate = self
    tablaVista.dataSource = self

}

func recuperaEmpresas(){

      menu = buscaEmp.getEmpresas()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return menu.count
}




func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.nombreEmp.text = menu[row][0]
    return cell

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    recuperaEmpresas()
    tablaVista.reloadData()
}
```

I use `viewWillAppear` to reload table before reopen the view.

Comment: Are you sure you want `[[]]` instead of `[]`?

Comment: Yes, after that on my other class y complete with JSon

Comment: Finally was my bad, I had missclick on my "forKey". Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in viewWillAppear, you have to call `recuperaEmpresas()` and after it, call `tableView.reloadData()`.

With this, it will refill the menu datasource with fresh data from `recuperaEmpresas()` and reload the table view with the new datasource values.

Edit :
 
And be sure that `recuperaEmpresas()` refresh data with new data, if it's always the same, you won't see any changes...

Comment: recuperaEmpresa just return value for my array

Comment: Yeah but it must retur. Different values each time if you want your cells update

Comment: i have a tableview and on didselect i m opening a url website through safari so i did changes in website and when i comeback from website and my app shows on same page i have to refresh tableview @David'mArm'Ansermot